# ReactJS: How to stop screen from refreshing State when window is resized?

Tags: reactjs, resize, state, page-refresh

Our React site has several component/pages that are basically CRUD processing: Collect several fields from the user, and on Submit store those fields as a database record.  Today's issue is that a user can fill out several fields, getting those values stored in State, and then lose everything if they resize the screen for any reason.  Apparently, "resize" automatically includes "refresh".

We want the new CSS to take effect (media-query for mobile vs desktop, for instance).  But we don't want all our values in State to be cleared out, and the screen reset to the beginning.

Is it possible to get what we want?

A typical field is

```
  <TextInput
             className={"required"}
             id="firstName"
             name="firstName"
             value={this.state.firstName}
             onChange={this.handleChange}
             placeholder="First Name"
             labelText="First Name"
             invalid={this.state.firstNameInvalid}
             invalidText="First Name is required"
```

The handleChange to put the input value into State is:

```
handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({[name]: value})
    }
```

Values in State work fine, until the window size is changed in any way: maximize/minimize/drag, turn a mobile device from vertical to horizontal, etc.  In that case, it behaves as if you had done a manual browser refresh: All State goes back to initial values.

One clue we're considering is that we are using the react-sidenav library along with react-router.  Would either of those cause something like this?

Comment: You might want to show some code.

Comment: I'm not sure what code I could show.  The issue is happening on multiple components, which are 500-1000 lines long.  I'll try...

Comment: State does not clear itself. You might have some hook/event/property registered which triggers it.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your code. This should not normally happen when resizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, we found the culprit.  In our wrapping nav.js, using react-sidenav, there was an on-resize handler that set the size into State.  By setting State, the sidenav re-rendered.  When that re-rendered, the react-router nested within it also re-rendered, essentially causing the page refresh.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Any recommendations for fixing the issue?

Comment: Nvm.. resolved by moving the BrowserRouter definition to a variable outside of the react-sidebar Navigation component definition. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I have the same issue, can you post the aswer here?